# Adverbial prepositional phrase order

Tags: adverbial-phrases

“I ate too much in the restaurant.”

“I ate in the restaurant too much.”

Is there a difference between them?

“too much” and “in the restaurant” are both adverbial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “I ate too much in the restaurant.”

This means you went to the restaurant on a single occasion and ate more food than you should have.

> “I ate in the restaurant too much.”

This means that went to the restaurant *too often*.

Comment: At least in Am.E (if not also Br.E?) we usually eat **at** a restaurant rather than **in** it.

Comment: @TypeIA both are common in BrEng.